What is the temperature at which plasma (the fourth state of matter) forms?
I wanted to know at what temperature plasma is formed? And what is its average temperature?
If possible, explain very simply.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

A plasma is defined to have a significant amount of free
charged particles (i.e. ions and electrons).
So the temperature needs to be high enough to ionize some atoms.
The ionization energy depends on which chemical element you have
(see here). It is somewhere between $4$ eV (for potassium atoms)
and $25$ eV (for helium atoms).
At temperature $T$ the particle energies are around $E\approx kT$
(where $k=8.6\cdot 10^{-5}$ eV/K is Boltzmann's constant).
So to get particle energies high enough to ionize at least
a few atoms, you need temperatures $T\approx 10^4$ K or higher.

using $E = kT$ is the correct approach, but it's not just about ionization. you need to knock a significant amount of electrons (if not all of them) out of their bound states. the energy required for this is significantly larger than the ionization energy for the valence shells.

This is like asking at what temperature liquid forms. Ice melts at one temperature, mercury at a colder temperature, steel at a very high temperature.
Atoms bounce around in a material. They bounce harder at higher temperatures. Plasma forms when the temperature is high enough that electrons on knocked off atoms. This takes some pretty hard knocks. Typically plasma forms at temperatures of thousands of degrees.

A plasma is created when electrons are stripped from atoms in a gas, leaving a mixture of negatively charged electrons and positively charged ions. The temperature of a plasma can be difficult to define, since these two components of the plasma can have very different temperatures (the plasma need not be in thermodynamic equilibrium).
Lightning is a plasma and is very hot (thousands of degrees). However, fluorescent tubes, neon lights and plasma globes all contain plasmas, but are cool to the touch because although the electrons in the plasma have a high temperature, there are relatively few of them and the individual electrons are very light compared to the ions that make up the rest of the plasma. Plasmas in these devices are created by applying a strong electric field to a gas rather than by heating it.

It seems to me that you are saying "Plasma does not need to be in thermodynamic equilibrium." It is incorrect! Only some types of plasma do not require thermodynamic equilibrium. For example, cold plasma(non-thermal plasma) does not need thermodynamic equilibrium; because the electron temperature is much hotter than the temperature of heavy species (ions and neutrals). As only electrons are thermalized, their Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution is very different from the ion velocity distribution.
But we have plasmas that have thermodynamic equilibrium. For example, hot plasma.

@Samyar Yes, I am saying "a plasma does not need to be in thermodynamic equilibrium". It can be in thermodynamic equilibrium - and some plasmas are - but it does not have to be - so some plasmas are not. If the plasma in a plasma globe were in thermodynamic equilibrium at a temperature of thousands of degrees then it would melt the enclosing glass globe wherever it touched it.
